# How to configure a Xalan 1.12.0 visual studio build to specify location of xerces inputs?

Tags: cmake, xalan

The website with building guidelines for xalan 1.12 for C++ at https://github.com/apache/xalan-c/blob/master/docs/build.md do not indicate how to instruct cmake on the location of the xerces header files and libs to build and link against. Generally, I know how to run cmake but not sure how I'm supposed to provide cmake with locations for dependencies in this case, especially since it is a multi-configuration build.

Let's assume that something like this would work.  If I can only install one prefix how do I configure such that the release and debug configs are both generated to link with the correct instance of the xerces artifact, and are these the right preprocessor macros to setup?

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=xalan_c-1.12-install `
  -Dsystem-encoding=ascii `
  -DXercesC_LIBRARY=libspath `
  -DXercesC_INCLUDE_DIR=includepath `
  -S xalan_c-1.12 `
  -B xalan_c-1.12-build
```